# Grok pattern works in Grok Debugger but not in logstash

Tags: regex

This is a line of my log

```
Dec 18, 2017 18:14:44:245 |Pal : DEBUG |Persistence-[CRA_GENERATION_THREADS-262]: COR:vm2: Find query :  : ( select T.type , T.id , T.groupeType , T.updatorUserId , T.fessAmount , T.currency$identifier , T.maxAmount , T.feeTypeIndex , T.fixedFeesAmount , T.feesRate , T.updateDate , T.version , T.creationDate , T.creatorUserId , T.localTaxeOnFeesAmount , T.isForcedFees , T.isCdscFee , T.localTaxeOnFeesRate from models_Fees T  left join T.orderOPC as T0 where T0.caceisReference = ?1  )
```

This the configuration

```
filter {
   grok {
     match => { "message"=>"%{GREEDYDATA:date} %{TIME:heure} %{GREEDYDATA:statut} \|%{GREEDYDATA:Couche}\-%{POSINT:thread}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:information} :Find query: :%{GREEDYDATA:query})" 
  }
}
```

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCSCm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest being a bit more careful with whitespaces: it  seems you have some in between colons and `Find query`.

Use `\s+` wherever you expect at least 1 space and use `[\s:]+` to match 1 or more whitespace or colon:

```
%{GREEDYDATA:date}\s+%{TIME:heure}\s+%{GREEDYDATA:statut}\s+\|%{GREEDYDATA:Couche}-%{POSINT:thread}\]:\s+%{GREEDYDATA:information}:\s+Find query[\s:]*%{GREEDYDATA:query}
```

This way, your `information` field will also be trimmed to `COR:vm2` (with no leading space).