# grok debugger passed but _grokparsefailure

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Here is my log

> INLFCW1MQ2.enterprisenet.org 11:55:57.818 [main] INFO GeneratorApplication - application 1 sample log

And here is the grok pattern in logstash

`filter {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGHOST:hostname}\s+%{TIME}\s+\[(?<threadname>[^\]]+)\]\s+%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s+%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
    }
}`

Pattern passed in grok debugger but fails in logstash. I have added white space after seeing this thread,
[Grok pattern works in Grok Debugger but not in logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424327/grok-pattern-works-in-grok-debugger-but-not-in-logstash)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
%{SYSLOGHOST:hostname} %{TIME:time} \[%{WORD:threadname}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

sometimes I got errors due to the `(?`